# i need to play video without sound in ipad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, audio, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using MPMoviePlayer in my project to play video. Now i need to play video without sound, as a user requirment.
Now i'm using this code for playing video when user select a button. Is there any API call to mute the sound of video?
please help me to find a solution.
Thank you so much for your feed back in advance.

```
    NSURL *urlforVideo = [NSURL URLWithString:symbolTalkEntry.fileName];
   MPMoviePlayerController  *dynamicScenePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlforVideo];
    dynamicScenePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:(use a value between 0.0 and 1.0)]
```

If your MPMoviePlayerController uses the application audio session, this works.